# Python: Scatterplot column names

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, scatter-plot

I'm trying to manipulate my dataframe so that the column names (ex Monday, Tuesday) can be used in the x-axis of the seaborn scatterplot (shown below). Right now I have this:

```
          week  Sun  Mon  Tues  Wed  Thur  Fri  Sat  
0   2016-05-08    0    0     0    3     1    5    1    
1   2016-05-15    0    0     0    1     0    0    1     
2   2016-05-22    0    0     1    2     3    0    0      
3   2016-05-29    0    0     1    0     0    0    0     
4   2016-06-05    0    0     3   19    19   14    1     
5   2016-06-12    0   40    30   14     0    0    0     
6   2016-06-19    3   16    10   26    38   17   17    
7   2016-06-26    0    4     3    1     1    4    0
```

The only thing I can think of is to change my data format so that it becomes something like this:

```
 week             day      amount
 2016-05-08       Sun           1
 2016-05-15       Sun          30
 2016-05-22       Sun           0
 2016-05-29       Mon           6
 2016-06-19       Mon          40
```

I'm a bit confused how I would unstack it.

Any direction of how I can accomplish that would be greatly appreciated.

[Scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc95u.png)

Comment: You could try to do some really novel unpivoting, or just process the rows into the new structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rearrange your data from a wide format to long format:

```
df.set_index('week').stack().rename_axis(('week','day')).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'amount'})
```

The picture you attached is a stripplot generated by Seaborn.

No data manipulation needed with Seaborn.

```
import seaborn as sns  
print(df)
             week     day  amount
0  2016-05-08  Sunday       1
1  2016-05-15  Sunday      30
2  2016-05-22  Sunday       0
3  2016-05-29  Monday       6
4  2016-06-19  Monday      40

_ = sns.stripplot('day', 'amount', data=df)
```

[image]

However, if you wanted to manipulate the data anyway, you can use the following commands:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['week','day']).unstack()
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.droplevel()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
day        Monday Sunday
week                    
2016-05-08    NaN    1.0
2016-05-15    NaN   30.0
2016-05-22    NaN    0.0
2016-05-29    6.0    NaN
2016-06-19   40.0    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The current format of my data frame isn't usable by seaborn yet. Any clue how I can reshape my data so that all the column days (Mon,Tues,Wed) go under one column?

Comment: df.set_index('week').stack().rename_axis(('week','day')).reset_index(level=1).rename(columns={0:'amount'})

Comment: @CaptamMorgan edit solution to show how to reshape your data from wide to long for use with Seaborn.